# Stop button going full width and keep navbar icon to the left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When the screen size is moved to `sm`, then the logout button width takes up the whole screen and the nav bar hamburger icon goes in the middle:

[image: pic1]

This is how it looks when it's normal:

[image: picture2]

Here is the code for it:

```
<!-- navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm bg-info navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNav">
                 <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
             </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Training</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">LOGOUT</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Logout</a>
  </nav>
```

Comment: You did not like any of our suggestions @mr.Banks?

Comment: love the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out that code. It works

```css
@media(max-width:777px){
  .btn-danger{
    max-width:70px!important;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm bg-info navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNav">
                 <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
             </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Training</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">LOGOUT</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Logout</a>
  </nav>
```

here you also have it on codepen.io 
https://codepen.io/hansfranz/pen/owmVod

What I did was setting up a [media Query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) here you can define the behavior for a specific `width`.

Hope that helps if not leave a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Using flexbox to organize the layout.

```css
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
  nav.navbar,
  .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0!important;
  }
  nav .btn.btn-danger {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm bg-info navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNav">
                 <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
             </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Training</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">LOGOUT</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Logout</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not leave the logout link outside the navbar div. Here is an example that could help.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
   </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
 </div>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
   </ul>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#">Link Button</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```